# How to make Amazon Mechanical Turk Input csv for my own photo?

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Currenty, I am working at a project that are using Amazon mechanical turk.
We managed to do it, but our problems are we got 2000+ pictures. We already have those file offile and I would like to put it as an input in my csv file. But looks like Amazon only take input which is URL. Any Idea ?
If it must be URL, I might get the URL everyone of them, but It will be time-consuming to put the URL one by one. Please help !

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your CSV and your question so far? This sounds like something that MTurk should be able to do just fine. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a project on the Requester website using the Tagging of An Image template to help you get started.

This will enable you to publish a batch with one HIT for each of the 2000+ photos.

After you save the project with any necessary updates to the instructions or options, you can choose Publish Batch from the "New Batch with an Existing Project" page to upload your CSV input file (label the header "image_url" without the quotes).

[This blog post](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-how-to-label-thousands-of-images-using-the-crowd-bea164ccbefc) gives more instructions. Since you already have URLs for all your images, you can skip the steps to upload them to Amazon Web Services Simple Storage Service (S3). The blog post also uses the Requester Sandbox (a free environment for testing your HITs before publishing them to Workers). You can test your HITs using Sandbox or follow the same instructions at requester.mturk.com

Hope this helps,

The Amazon Mechanical Turk Team